# Is there any point in having more than 100 dwellers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Once I've got 100 dwellers I started building Cola factories and now I threw out all newcomers because it seems like they are all similar in number of SPECIAL points and their configuration, so there is no point in waiting for any unusual one from the wasteland.

So is there any point is getting 110, 120, 150 or more dwellers? Would it give me some creepier invaders or smth?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are some triggers at certain number of dwellers to have different kinds of enemies; but I think the harder death claws come in at 60 or so dwellers.

No point really; it's just a game; grow your population to 200, level them all up to 50, and all SPECIAL to 10.

When you get to 200 dwellers, you can send out dwellers to die to be able to replace them with a better one (in case you win one with a lunchbox)

You also can role play; for example have all your dwellers wear a single outfit, or use the same weapon, ... or try to have all women or men dwellers....

Or just play the objectives.

Comment: You can just evict dwellers you no longer want